# Is a custom implementation required to  create notifications in iOs like the "Tweet Sent" notification the twitter app uses?

Tags: iphone, ios

Whenever you send a tweet using the twitter app, the statusbar at the top of the screen flips to say "Sending Tweet"... and then "Tweet Sent", and the toolbar at the top of the screen re-appears.  I'm guessing this is a custom implementation and not built in to the sdk.  Something like hiding the status bar showing those message views and then un-hiding the navigation bar.

I just want to make sure it is a custom implementation before I journey down the path to making something similar.  It's so well done, it looks like it's part of the os.

Thanks

Comment: yes u can make it.. apple has given the rights to hide the status bar any time in the app..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a custom implementation and Apple has allowed it in numerous apps even though it is a slight gray area according to the Human Interface Guidelines. It does lean more towards against the HIG, but they still allow it.

Here is a link to an excellent guide:

[[iOS] Custom status bar - Cocoa in the Shell](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2010/11/custom-status-bar-ios/)